# How to Dynamically link libraries in command line?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, linker, command-prompt

I have been struggling with this issue for a long time now, lets say i take notepad++ and write some quick c++ code using boost library 
and i use visual studio **Developer Command Prompt for VS2013** to compile with command prompt, I always get some linker errors like :

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-1_58.lib'`

but if i create an empty project in visual studio, add boost include and lib directories , the project will be built successfully. Apparently in command line the linking is static not dynamic.

my question is **How to Dynamically link libraries in command line ?**

Comment: Even linking a dynamic library (DLL) requires an import library during link.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the boost directory to the `%LIB%` environment variable, for example

```
set LIB=C:\boost\boost_1_57_0\stage\lib;%LIB%
```

Comment: i did it , i added **LIB** and **INCLUDE** to the environment variable , however  this is not the issue here

Comment: The error message indicates that the lib file cannot be found. So either you don't have that lib file, or you do not correctly specify the directory. Regardless whether you link dynamically or static, you always need a lib file. But the file name will be different.

Comment: yes the **-s prefix** in the lib file name means static linking, i think the normal build of boost library make only libs for dynamic linking , i looked it up and one solution is to make a complete build `.\b2 --build-type=complete` but this not an acceptable solution for me, the after build size alone of boost is a big inconvenience for me